# how to stop animation of QuartzCore-CABasicAnimation

Tags: swift

My animation works great although I want to add a toggle which pauses the animation by tapping  as you can see in the "is Anim' running"- the heart beats as you open the screen and by clicking on it- it stops returns to the original size

```
@IBOutlet var heartImage: UIButton!
var isAnimRunning = true

let pulseAnimation:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
           heartBit()
        }

        func heartBit(){
            if isAnimRunning == true{

                pulseAnimation.duration = 0.8
                pulseAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: 2.0)
                pulseAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE
                pulseAnimation.isCumulative = true
                pulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
                pulseAnimation.autoreverses = true
                pulseAnimation.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
                pulseAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(value: 0.0)

                self.view.layer.add(pulseAnimation, forKey: "transform.scale")
              //  self.view.layer.add(pulseAnimation, forKey: "transform.scale")
            }else if isAnimRunning == false{       //*****tried all that without any luck

                self.pulseAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: 1.0)

          //      self.view.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "transform.scale")
                //self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
                // view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
                //self.view.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "transform.scale")
               // self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()

            }

        }

        @IBAction func heartBtn(_ sender: Any) {
           isAnimRunning = !isAnimRunning
        }

    }
```

thanks for the helper. any question I'm available

AGAIN- when tapping make the heart stops and tapping again- the heart resume the animation

Comment: call removeanimation to romove animation

Comment: i called self.view.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "transform.scale") and it does not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To toggle the animation, i would like to update the `heartBit` method as below,

```
func heartBit() {
    isAnimRunning = !isAnimRunning

    if isAnimRunning == false { // Run animation if no animation
        pulseAnimation.duration = 0.8
        pulseAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: 2.0)
        pulseAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE
        pulseAnimation.isCumulative = true
        pulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        pulseAnimation.autoreverses = true
        pulseAnimation.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        pulseAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(value: 0.0)

        self.view.layer.add(pulseAnimation, forKey: "transform.scale")
    } else { // Remove animation if already running
        self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
}
```

And now you can call this method on `button click` same as you did in `viewDidLoad` and it will toggle the animation.

```
@IBAction func heartBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    heartBit()
}
```

**Note:** Make sure your `heartBtn` method is connected and getting called on button click. In my observation, its difficult to tap the button when the whole view is animating.

Comment: thank you @Kemran it's works!! do you know how shell I should go back to the original size and not freeze in the mid scaling of the heart

Comment: Didn't get that. `removeAllAnimations` should take it to original scale.